# Add delimiter in string coming from url in PHP

Tags: php, regex, arrays, string, curl

```
 Merchant Id|Merchant|Website|Transaction In Period|Voids In Period|Gross Sales Amount|Total Commision in Period         
 9766|Mountains Plus Outdoor Gear|www.MPGear.com|1|0|88.91|8.89 
 12447|Meritline.com|www.meritline.com|5|0|52.86|3.71
 16213|East Coast Fashions|www.discountstripper.com|1|0|32.27|3.23
 17226|HRM USA|www.HeartRateMonitorsUSA.com|1|0|189.9|6.65
```

I am getting above string from url now now I want convert that string to array based on split delimiter `|`

But there is a problem after end of each new row there is not placed delimiter `|` so I want that to placed that delimiter after each row end.

Note :: all columns will be predefined and it will return same all time request.

I am using this code to convert that string to array . This code is working perfect if there will be all delimiter placed correctly in string.

```
$NumColumns = 6;
$Delim = "|";
$data = array_chunk(explode($Delim,$contents), $NumColumns);
```

output will be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Merchant Id
            [1] => Merchant
            [2] => Website
            [3] => Transaction In Period
            [4] => Voids In Period
            [5] => Gross Sales Amount
            [6] => Total Commision in Period 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 9766
            [1] => Mountains Plus Outdoor Gear
            [2] => www.MPGear.com
            [3] => 1
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 88.91
            [6] => 8.89

        )  
        -----
        ----
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as a 2-step process. First split it into lines on the `\n` (newline) character, and then split each line on the `|` character.

You can do that in only a couple lines, like this:

```
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
$data = array_map(function($line) {return explode('|', trim($line));}, $lines);
```

You can see this working here: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9fv-h2c

Once I split the contents into individual lines, I'm using the [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) function to apply the same operation to every element of the array (every line).

[`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) calls a callback function (which I define as an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php)) for each element in the array. In this instance, I've defined a simple function that trims the line to remove any extra spaces there may be, and then splits it on the `|` character to get the individual fields.

If the array_map line is a bit complicated, I could illustrate how it's working by rewriting it without the [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) like this:

```
function processLine($line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    $fields = explode('|', $line);
    return $fields;
}
$data = array_map('processLine', $lines);
```

...or even rewriting it without using array_map like this:

```
function processLine($line) {
    $line = trim($line);
    $fields = explode('|', $line);
    return $fields;
}
$data = array();
foreach ($lines as $l) {
    $data[] = processLine($l);
}
```

Comment: ...Good work but there is no more \n in string its simple strig no more \n in that ...

Comment: @intekhabkhan The `\n` is interpreted as a newline character - which will match (and split on) the end of each line.

Answer (score 3):

Try using [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or [`explode`](http://php.net/explode).

```
<?php
    $data_from_url = "Merchant Id|Merchant|Website|Transaction In Period|Voids In Period|Gross Sales Amount|Total Commision in Period
9766|Mountains Plus Outdoor Gear|www.MPGear.com|1|0|88.91|8.89 
12447|Meritline.com|www.meritline.com|5|0|52.86|3.71
16213|East Coast Fashions|www.discountstripper.com|1|0|32.27|3.23
17226|HRM USA|www.HeartRateMonitorsUSA.com|1|0|189.9|6.65";
    $splitted_data = explode(PHP_EOL, $data_from_url);
    /**
     * print_r($splitted_data) will be
     * Array
     * (
         [0] => "Merchant Id|Merchant|Website|Transaction In Period|Voids In Period|Gross Sales Amount|Total Commision in Period"
         [1] => "9766|Mountains Plus Outdoor Gear|www.MPGear.com|1|0|88.91|8.89"
         ...
     * )
     */
     // You can now iterate through the lines
     $output1 = array();
     foreach($splitted_data as $row) {
        $output1[] = str_getcsv(trim($row), '|'); // parses a 
        // OR
        //$output1[] = explode('|', trim($row));
     }
     // OR use array_map with callback function
     $output2 = array_map(function($line){ return explode('|', trim($line)); }, $splitted_data);
     $output3 = array_map(function($line){ return str_getcsv(trim($line), '|'); }, $splitted_data);
     var_dump($output1, $output2, $output3); // The result you want to achive
?>
```

Comment: I have updated the post ... Please review that .. I m only getting string coming from url with add some delimiter in each columns.

Comment: Thanks for giving me answer But my requirement is that what i was looking at end of this post.

Comment: The output will be what you wrote in your question.

Comment: @fraces .. I have chnged the question .. Please read there is no more csv file.. There is only simple string ..thats it you have to get output which I m looking for now

Comment: As you can see in my answer there is no file there. Only a CSV parser which can help you. Please review my answer.

Comment: @Fraces .. Can you please help to get that output via adding in my code or update code ...or use your code.. any help will be appreciate in advance..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32542/discussion-between-fracsi-and-intekhab-khan)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you're trying to split the data, but want to keep the delimiter `|` as part of the string.
Using `preg_split`, you can do this like so:

```
$arr = preg_split('/([^|]*\|)/', $string, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

The expression matches zero or more chars that *aren't* `|` (`[^|]*`)
and matches the delimiting `|`. the combination of the two is used as delimiter. In other words, *everything* is a delimiter now.
That's why we have to use the predefined constant `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPUTRE`.

Of course, between the delimiters, there's nothing, but `preg_split` will capture this nothing-ness, too and add empty matches in the resulting array. That's why we have to use the other predefined constant: `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY`.
The two constants are combined by means of the bitwise OR operator `|`

```
$output = explode(PHP_EOL, $input);
foreach($output as &$line)
{//$line is a reference here, important!
    $line = preg_split('/([^|]*\|)/', $line, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
}
```

This should produce the desired ouptut, assuming you want the delimiting `|` kept in the strings. if not:

```
$output = explode(PHP_EOL, $input);
foreach($output as &$line)
{
    $line = explode('|', $line);
}
```

That's it, really...

Comment: Thanks .. But I want to convert that string in array .. Have a look output attached at end of this post.

Comment: @intekhabkhan: just explode the string using `explode(PHP_EOL, $string)` and apply the `preg_split` to each line... create an array, for each line, push the return value of the code above into that array, and you're there...

Comment: Thanks @Elias  but there is combination of string with "|" or spaces and also end of each row .. If you could help me i I will appreciate that.  

As per your code I got this output.. I want the output as I say under this post
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Website|Transaction In Period|Voids In Period|Gross Sales Amount|Total Commision in Period 9766|Mountains Plus Outdoor Gear|www.MPGear.com|1|0|88.91|8.89

Comment: @Ellias .. Can you please help to get that output via adding in my code or update code ...or use your code.. any help will be appreciate in advance..